# failed to access firebase database in vuejs2

Tags: vuejs2

I am new to vuejs and trying to access firebase real-time database in my app.

**signup.vue**

```
<template>
 <div>
  <p v-for="(data,index) in fbData" :key="index">{{data.id1}}</p>
 </div>
</template>
<script>
    import { validationMixin } from 'vuelidate'
    import { required, email, minLength, maxLength } from 'vuelidate/lib/validators';
    import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex';
    import firebase from 'firebase/app';
    import 'firebase/database';

    let config = {
        config properties
    }
    let app = firebase.initializeApp(config);
    let db = app.database();
    let datas = db.ref('users');
    export default {
        name:'signUp',

        data() {
            return {
                fbData:{},
            }
        },

        firebase:{
            fbData:datas
        }
</script>
```

but it doesn't display anything in the html. What I missed here? How can I access a firebase database in vuejs2?

Comment: did you get errors in your console?

Answer (score 0):

issue solved by adding vuefire to the app.